# PHP - Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php, mysql

When I load my page I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\cglst\images\addform.php on line 16
```

Here are my first 28 lines of code:

```
//load listings from database:
require_once "login.php";
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

//to do: redirect to an "error encountered page"
if (!$db_server)
    die("Unable to connect to MySql databse: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$deleted=false;

//if record deletion was selected, delete the record:
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST('delid'))) // <-- line 16
{
    $deleted = true;
    $delID = get_post('delid');
    $query = 'PREPARE statement FROM "DELETE FROM bix WHERE ID=?"';
    mysql_query($query);
    $query = 'SET @ID = "' . $delID . '"';
    mysql_query($query);
    $query = 'EXECUTE statement USING @ID';
    mysql_query($query);
    $query = 'DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement';
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

The code is all pretty self-explanatory-- I'm opening a database and if deletion of data has been requested it deletes that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST('delid')` should be either `$_POST['delid']` or `get_post('delid')`